# android mask bitmap

Tags: android, image, paint, mask

I need to create a custom view amd in `onDraw` method I need to draw some bitmaps, using a mask. I created a paint:

```
    Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.RED, 0, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));
```

and I draw my bitmap on canvas using this paint. My problem is that at the corners, my mask have some pixels with alpha less than 255. Is there a way to draw my bitmap's pixels on the mask with the same alpha that mask image has on those pixels with aplha greater than zero?

Comment: You could try to increase the tolerance?

Comment: no use, color is the same on the mask, the alpha is different at the corners... but the color remain the same

Comment: Hm, that is a bit unexpected. Usually one would assume that a change in alpha would be equal to a change in other channels.

Answer (score 3):

```
private Bitmap maskingImage(Bitmap s, int drawable) {
        Bitmap original = s;
        Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),drawable);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources resources = this.getResources();
Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.fx_lightleak2_small);
int width=bMap.getWidth();
int height=bMap.getHeight();
Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mask, width, height, true);

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN));
c.drawBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, null);
paint.setAlpha(200);
c.drawBitmap(resizedbitmap, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(null);
effect_5.setImageBitmap(result);
```